# Avoid data augmentation on validation set when splitting training set dynamically

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, keras

Hi I've a dataset of jpg images, I'm using Keras with Tensorflow.
My dataset has 2 subdirs: *training* and *test*.
I want to split dynamically my *training* in a *validation* part.
I've seen that `ImageDataGenerator` has a method called `validation_split`.
My problem is that I want also to apply data augmentation but only on the remaining *training* part.

Here's the code (it also applies data augmentation on *validation* part)

```
apply_data_augmentation = True

if apply_data_augmentation:
  train_data_gen = ImageDataGenerator(rotation_range=10,
                                      width_shift_range=10,
                                      height_shift_range=10,
                                      zoom_range=0.3,
                                      horizontal_flip=True,
                                      vertical_flip=True,
                                      fill_mode='constant',
                                      cval=0,
                                      shear_range=0.2,
                                      rescale=1./255,
                                      validation_split=0.2)#means 20% of training is splitted dinamically into validation
else:
  train_data_gen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1./255,
                                      validation_split=0.2)
  
train_gen = train_data_gen.flow_from_directory(training_dir,
                                               target_size=(image_h, image_w),
                                               batch_size=bs,
                                               subset='training',
                                               class_mode='categorical',
                                               shuffle=True,
                                               classes=['NO_MASK','ALL_MASK','SOME_MASK'],
                                               seed=SEED,
                                               color_mode="rgb")

valid_data_gen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1./255)

valid_gen = train_data_gen.flow_from_directory(validation_dir,
                                               target_size=(image_h, image_w),
                                               batch_size=bs,
                                               subset='validation',
                                               class_mode='categorical',
                                               shuffle=True,
                                               classes=['NO_MASK','ALL_MASK','SOME_MASK'],
                                               seed=SEED,
                                               color_mode="rgb")
```

Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

I am confused, do you have separate training and validation directories? If you do then create two separate generators for training and validation.

```
valid_gen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1/255).flow_from_directory(validation_dir,                                               
                                               target_size=(image_h, image_w),
                                               batch_size=bs,
                                               subset=None
                                               class_mode='categorical',
                                               shuffle=False,
                                               classes=['NO_MASK','ALL_MASK','SOME_MASK'],
                                               seed=SEED,
                                               color_mode="rgb")
```

remove the validation split parameter in the train_data_gen. If all your images are in the  training directory then for the valid_gen use the code below.

```
valid_gen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1/255, 
                               validation_split=0.2).flow_from_directory(training_dir,
                                               target_size=(image_h, image_w),
                                               batch_size=bs,
                                               subset='validation',
                                               class_mode='categorical',
                                               shuffle=False,
                                               classes=['NO_MASK','ALL_MASK','SOME_MASK'],
                                               seed=SEED,
                                               color_mode="rgb")
```

For the  train_gen use the code you have. Make sure that in the second case you use the same seed value in both the train_gen and the valid_gen. For validation it is best to set shuffle=False that way the same images in
the same order are used for validation on each epoch.

Comment: No, I haven't separate training and validation directories.
I've only training directory and I want to create validation data dynamically (using validation_split method in ImageDataGenerator)